# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'I' to data type int

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this query and when I execute it the following error appears.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'I' to data type int

The query is for get a report of the account status customer. the module in the software is accounts receivable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Id_Cliente,
           TipoDeDocumento AS Id_Tipo,
           iif ( TipoDeDocumento in ('1','3','4'), 'Factura', 'Nota de Credito' ) AS Tipo,
           Movi_CartaPorte.Id_CartaPorte,
           Movi_CartaPorte.Folio,
           iif ( TipoDeDocumento in ('1','3','4'), Total, NULL) AS Cargo,
           iif ( TipoDeDocumento in ('2'), Total, NULL) AS Abono,
           Total,
           Fecha 
    FROM Movi_CartaPorte
    WHERE Id_StatusCartaPorte <> 100  
    AND 1 = 1

    UNION
    SELECT  Id_Cliente,
            1000 AS Id_Tipo, 
            'DEPÓSITO' AS Tipo,
            Id_CartaPorte,
            Descripcion AS Folio ,
            NULL AS Cargo,
            Importe AS Abono,
            Importe AS Total,
            Fecha 
    FROM Movi_CartaPorteCobranza 
    WHERE 1 = 1

) AS tabla 
ORDER BY Fecha
```

Comment: which line is giving you this error?

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Comment: I think the issue is here

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Try running the inner query... Do you get an error?

Comment: Start by running each inner query alone. 
If you get the error, you've narrowed the search.
If you don't get that error, it's something to do with the union - One of the columns in `Movi_CartaPorte` is int while the corresponding column in `Movi_CartaPorteCobranza` is not and contains `I`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I found the detail, this query is for be executed on MS Access when you tried to execute it on SQL Server it launch error.